# Set caption to always begin in the photo's left corner

Tags: html, css

I have a photo caption. It works nicely when the browser is not
bigger than the photo size. When it is bigger, the photo is in the
center. I don't know how I can make the caption always begin in the photo's left corner.

HTML

```
<div>
<img id="pht" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3065/2741653860_468fda7e7a.jpg">
    <span id="cap">Photo Caption</span>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
#pht{
position:relative;
    display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

}
#cap{position:absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) none repeat scroll 0 0;

    color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    font: bold 13px/30px Helvetica,sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    padding-left: 5pt;
    padding-right: 5pt;   
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qpxkypn8/

Comment: This what i made http://jsfiddle.net/qpxkypn8/ just can't attach

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning?

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div id="dpht"><img id="pht" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3065/2741653860_468fda7e7a.jpg"></div>
    <span id="cap">Photo Caption</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#dpht{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#pht{
    display: block;
}
#cap{
    flex: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) none repeat scroll 0 0;

    color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    font: bold 13px/30px Helvetica,sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    padding-left: 5pt;
    padding-right: 5pt;   
}
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5eft71hg/)

Comment: sorry adding width:500px will crash the responsiveness in my case.
Do you know how to keep responsive?

Comment: using 100% the caption not follow the image left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS

```
div {
    position: relative;  /* positions absolutely-positioned 
                           children relative to this element */
    display: inline-block;  /* makes the div only as large as its img child */
}

#cap {
    top: 100%;  /* these put #cap under the */
    left: 0;    /* bottom left corner of the img */
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpxkypn8/2/)

Comment: well the photo is stays on the left side insted of center

Comment: Don't you want it on the left?

Comment: the photo must be centered and the caption must be on the left

Comment: So to the left of the image?  Or in front of the image but in the left corner?  Your question and comments are kind of ambiguous.  You could post a picture of what you want.  I hear they're worth a thousand words :)

Comment: This is what i need :http://jsfiddle.net/hkqgkee5/ but i have to keep it responsive

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to alter the HTML?  If so, you could use a container div to achieve the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/hkqgkee5/

To center a div using auto margins, you generally need to specify a width explicitly.  Using `display: table` on the containing div will allow you to bypass that restriction.